# REGEX_EXTRACT error in PIG

Tags: apache-pig

I have a CSV file with 3 columns: `tweetid` , `tweet`, and `Userid`. However within the `tweet` column there are  comma separated values.

i.e. of 1 row of data:

```
`396124437168537600`,"I really wish I didn't give up everything I did for you, I'm so mad at my self for even letting it get as far as it did.",savava143
```

I want to extract all 3 fields individually, but `REGEX_EXTRACT` is giving me an error with this code:

```
a = LOAD tweets USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1,f2,f3);

b = FILTER a BY REGEX_EXTRACT(f1,'(.*)\\"(.*)',1);
```

The error is:

```
error: Filter's condition must evaluate to boolean.
```

Answer (score 2):

In the use case shared, reading the data using PigStrorage(',') will result in missing savava143 (last field value)

```
A = LOAD '/Users/muralirao/learning/pig/a.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS (f1,f2,f3);
DUMP A;
```

**Output : A :** Observe that the last field value is missing.

```
(396124437168537600,"I really wish I didn't give up everything I did for you, I'm so mad at my self for even letting it get as far as it did.")
```

For the use case shared, to extract all the values from CSV file with field values having ',' we can use either CSVExcelStorage or CSVLoader.

**Approach 1 : Using  CSVExcelStorage**

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVExcelStorage.html

**Input : a.csv**

```
396124437168537600,"I really wish I didn't give up everything I did for you, I'm so mad at my self for even letting it get as far as it did.",savava143
```

**Pig Script :**

```
REGISTER piggybank.jar;
A = LOAD 'a.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVExcelStorage() AS (f1,f2,f3); 
DUMP A;
```

**Output : A**

```
(396124437168537600,I really wish I didn't give up everything I did for you, I'm so mad at my self for even letting it get as far as it did.,savava143)
```

**Approach 2 : Using CSVLoader**

Ref : http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/api/org/apache/pig/piggybank/storage/CSVLoader.html

Below script makes use of CSVLoader(), DUMP A will result in the same output seen earlier.

```
A = LOAD 'a.csv' USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.CSVLoader() AS (f1,f2,f3);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that you do not want to `FILTER` based on a regex but `GENERATE` new fields based on a regex. To filter, you need to know if the line have to be filtered, hence the boolean requirement.

Therefore, you have to use :

```
b = FOREACH a GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(FIELD, REGEX, HOW_MANY_GROUPS_TO_RETURN);
```

However, as @Murali Rao said, your values are not just coma separated but CSV (think how you will handle a coma in tweet : it is not a field separator, just some content).